Problem while loading imagaes in Vercel Webpage deployment
I made a website where images are showing when hosted locally (vs code live server) but when I uploaded it to Vercel, the images are not showing.
repo: https://github.com/ShakhorChowdhury/LawyerPortfolio/tree/main/src/img
vercel deployment:  https://lawyer-portfolio-wheat.vercel.app/
This is the website when hosted locally
This is the website when hosted on Vercel
I expected the website deployed to vercel to show the images.

Deployed site is dead.
Image loading may be slow, or path setting may be wrong.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I downloaded the file from the repository and tested it.
JS animation according to scrolling worked normally.
I can't see a few texts in the screenshot. I think it didn't work well during the full page capture
It seems necessary to modify the path in the file to be deployed directly or to apply it in batches through configs.
wrong path
...
<div class="bg-[#f8f9fa]" style="background-image: url(./src/img/ooorganize\ \(9\).svg);">
...
<img class="h-12" src="/Public/law.png" alt="">
...

to
...
<div class="bg-[#f8f9fa]" style="background-image: url(./Public/ooorganize\ \(9\).svg);">
...
<img class="h-12" src="./Public/law.png" alt="">
...

